# delegate - error(-5): Timeout sending message

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, smtp

I am sending email in background. Sometimes i get this error and can not send email. I have changed connection time out but still i am facing this issue.I am using [SKPSSMTP](https://github.com/jetseven/skpsmtpmessage). 
i have changed
  connectTimeout = 8.0; to  connectTimeout = 16.0;

Comment: Please make sure the class set as delegate is alive when the callback is being invoked ?

Comment: yes i have checked that too @NeverHopeless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have network access. Also, the mail server may not respond within the given timeframe even so you have network. Thus you receive the error message. Keep the 8 seconds timeout and upon receiving the timeout retry. At some point store the mail and inform the user.